# center horizontally an unspecified number of divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to implement a button that adds a X number of elements next to each other (horizontally), but lets say everything should look centered, so the first div should appear in the middle, but if I clic again, the second div should appear next to the first one, but they both must look equally centered, and so on.

I really don't know if I explained myself and thanks in advance.

Comment: `display` elements as `inline-block` and give `text-align: center` to the container,

Comment: Questions like this usually make more sense with a simple MsPaint.exe illustration.

Answer (score 0):

Center-align the container of the divs, and display the divs inline.

```js
$('.newDiv').on('click', function() {
    $('.container').append('<div class="test">test</div>');
});
```

```css
.container {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background: aqua;
    text-align: center;
}
.test {
    display: inline;
    background: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="newDiv" href="#">add div</a>
<div class="container"></div>
```